# How to pass all user's data when clicking edit button?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I created a display page using `php` where all users records are displayed in a table and there are delete and edit buttons to manage users, for the delete option I managed to do it but it's been hours since yesterday trying to do the edit button. I want all the user's data (full_name, email, password...city) to be passed from the `display.php` page to the `update.php`, and I want the new data that will be updated to be keyed in by a form which I made it as `updateform.html` but I got studck on how to connect these 3 files to successfully update the users detail.

Here are the files:

**display.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1.5px solid #d9d9d9;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        </div>

    <div class="container">

        <?php

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finalproject") or die("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users" or die("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        ?>

        <div class="row justify-contect-center">
            <table class="table" border-size="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Phone Number</th>
                        <th>Work Duration</th>
                        <th>IG Account</th>
                        <th>State</th>
                        <th>Postcode</th>
                        <th>City</th>
                        <th>Action</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php
                //while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()); 
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) :
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['full_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['password'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['age'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['phone_number'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['work_duration'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ig_account'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['postcode'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['city'] ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="updateform.html?edit=<?php if(isset($username)){
                                $conn->query("Select * from users where username='$username'");
                            } ?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>

                            <a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>

        </div>

        <?php
        function pre_r($array)
        {
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($array);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

        ?>

</body>

</html>
```

**updateform.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <title>Update Information</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="update.php" method="POST" class="login-email">
            <p class="login-text" style="font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 800;">Update Information</p>
 
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Full Name:
                <input type="text" name="full_name" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Email:
                <input type="email" name="email" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Password:
                <input type="password" name="password" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Confirm Password:
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Age:
                <input type="text" name="age" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Gender:
                <label for="f-option" class="l-radio" value="">
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="1" value="Male" style="margin-left:10px;">
                    <span> Male</span>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="2" value="Female" style="margin-left:20px;">
                    <span> Female</span>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Phone Number:
                <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Work Duration:
                <input type="text" name="work_duration" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">IG Account:
                <input type="text" name="ig_account" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <label>State:</label>
                <select name="state" class="form-control" value="" required>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Postcode:
                <input type="text" name="postcode" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">City:
                <input type="text" name="city" value="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:40px;">
                <button name="update" class="btn">Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**update.php**

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "finalproject") or die("<script>alert('Connection Failed.')</script>");

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];
    $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
    $work_duration = $_POST['work_duration'];
    $ig_account = $_POST['ig_account'];
    $state = $_POST["state"];
    $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

}
?>
```

Comment: Is your updateform.html capable of executing PHP code ?

Comment: No, I can only fill the form but when I click update, the values are not updated.

Comment: Do you have a key field in your db table ?

Comment: you mean id? yes I have

Comment: Then better use id as a key determining the record for updating / deletion.  (imagine that you have two records with the same username, then if you perform deletion it may delete both.)

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a lot of issues with your code, so I went above and beyond to recode it for you and even did the update part for you and hopefully you learn a few tricks from it. I assume your fairly new to the game based on your code... I added extra files to make your life easier in long run.

*A few tips

- You don't need to use ?> to close php at the end of a file
- `<?=$username?>` is the same as `<? echo $username; ?>`. Easy on eyes, simple.
- Try not to use tables, I didn't go as far as messing with your but check out flex for tables or use div
- don't use border-size in html tables... try not to use style in anything in html... always use css. classes are used multiple times .classname and ID's are only used once #idname*

**_config.php**
Put your db and other settings in this file to be included into all your pages so your not wasting your time writing the same thing over and over

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'riseofwar_v1');
if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

**_funcs.php**
I'm giving you my basic library to use to sanitize your input fields

```
<?php
include('_config.php');

// BASIC FUNCTIONS; Carry this library to all your future projects too!
function abc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z]+$/i', $input); }
function abcSpc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z\ ]*$/i', $input); }
function abcNum ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumSpc ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9\ ]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumU ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9_-]+$/i', $input); }
function abcNumD ($input){ return preg_match('/^[A-Z0-9-]+$/i', $input); }
function num ($input){ if(strlen($input) > 24){ $input=0; }if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', $input)){ $input=0; } return $input; }
function numDot ($input){ if(strlen($input) > 24){ $input=0; }if(!preg_match('/^[0-9.]+$/', $input)){ $input=0; } return $input; }
function numU ($input){ return preg_match('/^[0-9_-]+$/i', $input); }
function is_odd($num){ return($num & 1); }
function email ($input){ return filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); }
function phone ($input){ $phone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input); if(strlen($phone) < 10 || !num($phone)) { $input=false; } return $input; }
function is_url($input){ return preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}'.'((:[0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$/i',$input); }
function is_uri ($input){ return preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-]+$/i', $input); }
function findIt($find,$string){ return preg_match("/$find/i","$string"); }
```

**_html.php** You'll love this... modify your header and footer for every html page you create... This is the file you include in all your existing and new pages.

```
<?php
include('_funcs.php');

// Simple function you can call on every page so you don't have to edit each file every time you change something in the headers
function head($title){?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title><?=$title?></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?
}

// Same as the above function, just the footer
function foot(){?>
    </body>
    </html>
<? }
```

**display.php**

```
<?php
include('_html.php');

head('Viewing Users');
?>
<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-contect-center">
        <table class="table" border-size="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Full Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Phone Number</th>
                <th>Work Duration</th>
                <th>IG Account</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Postcode</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php
            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 25;");
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['full_name'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['password'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['age'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['phone_number'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['work_duration'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ig_account'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['state'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['postcode'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['city'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="edit.php?id=<?=$row['id']?>" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>

                        <a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <?}?>
        </table>

    </div>
<? foot();
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
include('_html.php');

$id = num($_GET['id']) ?: false; // Check the ID in the URL to make sure it's a number

$user = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id'")->fetch_assoc();

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {

    // CHECK VALUES BEFORE YOU UPDATE THEM
    $user['full_name'] = abcSpc($_POST['full_name']) ? $_POST['full_name'] : $user['full_name'];
    $user['email'] = email($_POST['email'])  ? $_POST['email'] : $user['email'];
    $user['password'] = abcNum($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : $user['password'];
    $user['password'] = $user['password'] != $user['cpassword'] ? $user['password'] : $_POST['password'];
    $user['phone_number'] = phone($_POST['phone_number']) ? $_POST['phone_number'] : $user['phone_number'];
    $user['work_duration'] = num($_POST['work_duration']) ? $_POST['work_duration'] : $user['work_duration'];
    $user['ig_account'] = abcSpc($_POST['ig_account']) ? $_POST['ig_account'] : $user['ig_account'];
    $user['state'] = num($_POST["state"]) ? $_POST['state'] : $user['state'];
    $user['postcode'] = abc($_POST['postcode']) ? $_POST['postcode'] : $user['postcode'];
    $user['city'] = num($_POST['city']) ? $_POST['city'] : $user['city'];
    $user['gender'] = num($_POST['gender'])  ? $_POST['gender'] : $user['gender'];
    $user['age'] = num($_POST['age']) ? $_POST['age'] : $user['age'];

    $msg = 'Updated! <a href="display.php">View all users again</a>';

    $db->query("UPDATE users SET full_name='$user[full_name]', email='$user[email]', password='$user[password]', phone_number='$user[phone_number]', work_duration='$user[work_duration]', ig_account='$user[ig_account]', state='$user[state]', postcode='$user[postcode]', city='$user[city]', gender='$user[gender]', age='$user[age]' WHERE id='$user[id]';");
}




head('Update Information');
?>
<?=$msg?>
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" class="login-email">
        <p class="login-text" style="font-size: 2rem; font-weight: 800;">Update Information</p>

        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Full Name:
            <input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?=$user['full_name']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Email:
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?=$user['email']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Password:
            <input type="password" name="password" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Confirm Password:
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Age:
            <input type="text" name="age" value="<?=$user['age']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: 20px;">Gender:
            <label for="f-option" class="l-radio" value="">
                <input type="radio" name="gender" checked tabindex="1" value="Male" style="margin-left:10px;">
                <span> Male</span>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" tabindex="2" value="Female" style="margin-left:20px;">
                <span> Female</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Phone Number:
            <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="<?=$user['phone_number']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Work Duration:
            <input type="text" name="work_duration" value="<?=$user['work_duration']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">IG Account:
            <input type="text" name="ig_account" value="<?=$user['ig_account']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <label>State:</label>
            <select name="state" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="1" <?=$state==1?'checked':''?>>Option 1</option>
                <option value="2" <?=$state==2?'checked':''?>>Option 2</option>
                <option value="3" <?=$state==3?'checked':''?>>Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 40px;">Postcode:
            <input type="text" name="postcode" value="<?=$user['postcode']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">City:
            <input type="text" name="city" value="<?=$user['city']?>" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group" style="margin-top:40px;">
            <button name="update" class="btn">Update</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<? foot();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I noticed your issue while I am working on your new code, I'm not done yet though, give me about 20 more mins. Hoping for the winning answer. You'll like what I did for you. BRB

Comment: almost done the re-code i did for you, 5 more mins

Comment: Done... if theres any issues or you have more questions, feel free to ask me. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you soo much for your efforts and help, I really do appreciate it. I will now check them and edit my code.

Comment: Hey there, I modified my code but I can't run anything because it says undefined function for all the functions in (_funcs.php), although I included it in the same folder

Comment: I'm still here, it worked on my server, let me just make sure i copied and pasted everything correctly.

Comment: Hrm... it works on my server. Everything looks good here... try finding the issue by going to _html.php, change the include file from _funcs.php to _config.php.... then go to both display & edit.php and try adding the _funcs.php file directly there and see if that works. If that works, then try switching it back. What PHP version are you using? If you don't know you can write `echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion();` to find out... I built the script on php8.... I may need to downgrade for you. If you want to see it working, check out https://riseofwar.com/stack/display.php

Comment: BTW sorry I took 6 hours to reply, I've been up for 24 hours now programming, took a tv break. I'm keep on eye on this for you to make sure you figure this out. You got this!

Comment: I updated the edit.php file, i found an error while testing it again. Not related to functions undefined though.